# How does Firebase.auth.currentUser work internally?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

What exactly does `Firebase.auth.currentUser` do, especially: are there cases where this makes any network requests, e.g. to check if a token is still valid? Or is this always just a simple property that can be checked "instantly" without any waiting time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just returns the user object at the current moment in time.  That's all.  You can check this for yourself by using Android Studio to view the decompiled source code of the FirebaseAuth class.  The Android SDK does not perform any blocking operations.  Anything that requires a network connection would return a [Task](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/tasks/Task) object for you to get a callback since you have no guarantee how well that network operates.

This is the way it works on all client platforms.